# Make sure attribute is used with static methods only

Tags: c#, attributes

Is there a way to tell attribute to work only when used with static methods?

`AttributeUsage` class does not seem to allow such specyfic usage.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method,
                Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no way to restrict this. However - you could use reflection at run-time to enforce this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature available in C#  that allows you to restrict attribute usage based on a member's accessibility.